# Tagging a single word with the nltk pos tagger tags each letter instead of the word

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm try to tag a single word with the nltk pos tagger:

```
word = "going"
pos = nltk.pos_tag(word)
print pos
```

But the output is this:

```
[('g', 'NN'), ('o', 'VBD'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('n', 'VBP'), ('g', 'JJ')]
```

It's tagging each letter rather than just the one word.

What can I do to make it tag the word?

Comment: Note that tagging a single word is not going to give you satisfactory results. Think about it: If looking at individual words was enough, we wouldn't need taggers-- we'd just look up the POS in a dictionary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`nltk.tag.pos_tag`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.pos_tag) accepts a list of tokens, separate and tags its elements. Therefore you need to put your words in an iterable like list:

```
>>> nltk.tag.pos_tag(['going'])
[('going', 'VBG')]
```

Comment: Note that this tags the **sentence** as whole (I know the OP asked about 1 word but this might be confusing)

Comment: @AlaaM. What do you mean by tagging a sentence as a whole? The  `pos` tagging aims to tag the words based on their initial character and their position in the sentence. That's why the tag is composed of multiple character.

Comment: I'm just saying if you have more than one word then do `nltk.tag.pos_tag('a sentence'.split())`, and not `nltk.tag.pos_tag(['a sentence'])`, because the latter would produce a single tag

Comment: @AlaaM. Definitely, that's why I liked to the documentation. Also I updated the answer since it was for a long while ago and full of confusion ;)).

Comment: This is just a technical (and probably overly pedantic) clarification. The problem is that `pos_tag` accepts any iterable, not just lists. It iterates over the items in that iterable (characters in the case of strings, items in the case of lists) and attempts to tag those items. I'm sure you are aware of this, but I thought I would just provide more clarification for those who are wondering why the output is the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> word = 'going'
>>> word = nltk.word_tokenize(word)
>>> l1 = nltk.pos_tag(word)
>>> l1
[('going', 'VBG')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the `POS` tag of one word

```py
nltk.pos_tag(["going"])
----->[('going', 'VBG')]
```

Comment: This solution has already been provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397935/12268505).

Answer (score 0):

The tagger works on a list of words. To turn the string into a list simply use something like

```
word_list = [word]
```

then use the pos tagger on the `word_list`. Note that if you have more than one word, you should run `nltk.word_tokenize` on the string first.

As for the success in tagging only one word, you should look into the lookup tagger mentioned in section 4.3 [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html). The `pos_tag` used by nltk is more complicated than just a one word lookup tagger, but it does use one as part of the process, so you should see ok results.

Comment: I know it's meant to work on list but can it work on a single word?